# Testing Devise with minitest, "undefined method 'registration_path'" (Cloud9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cloud9-ide, minitest

Using the Cloud9 IDE. I'm writing tests for a Rails 4.2.5 app running Devise 4, it's supposed to test both signing up for the app with both an invalid and valid information. Using the default routes for Devise, I wrote the following tests:

```
class UserSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "invalid signup information" do
    get new_user_registration_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post user_registration_path, user: { name: '',
                                   email: 'user@invalid',
                                   password: 'foo',
                                   password_confirmation: 'bar' }
    end
    assert_template 'devise/registrations/new'
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
  end

  test 'valid signup information' do
    get new_user_registration_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post user_registration_path, user: { name: "Example User",
                                           email: "user@example.com",
                                           password:              "password",
                                           password_confirmation: "password" }
    end
  end
end
```

Using Guard for automated testing, I receive the following errors:

```
ERROR["test_invalid_signup_information", UserSignupTest, 2016-02-17 20:06:09 +0000]
 test_invalid_signup_information#UserSignupTest (1455739569.24s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `registration_path' for #:0x00000004007950>
            app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2481304939547746105_41543060'
            test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:5:in `block in '
        app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2481304939547746105_41543060'
        test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:5:in `block in '

ERROR["test_valid_signup_information", UserSignupTest, 2016-02-17 20:06:09 +0000]
 test_valid_signup_information#UserSignupTest (1455739569.30s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `registration_path' for #:0x000000052db2c0>
            app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2481304939547746105_41543060'
            test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:17:in `block in '
        app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2481304939547746105_41543060'
        test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:17:in `block in '
```

It works when I access the signup page myself, so I think this is something to do with the testing. I haven't seen anything else about this particular problem, so I think it's a problem with the Cloud9 IDE itself, or Minitest not having access to the `registration_path` method. I've included the Devise test helpers in my `test_helper.rb` file, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You may need to set your application preview to public, otherwise the test will be asked to login when it runs through. Do this by opening the share dialog from the top right of the workspace and checking "public" next to the application URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @BradyDowling! I've tried to do that, but the checkbox is grayed out and already checked. The workspace is already public, I believe.